# More convenient way to work with strings in winapi calls

Tags: string, winapi, rust

I'm looking for more convenient way to work with `std::String` in winapi calls in Rust.

Using rust v 0.12.0-nigtly with winapi 0.1.22 and user32-sys 0.1.1

Now I'm using something like this:

```
use winapi;
use user32;

pub fn get_window_title(handle: i32) -> String {
    let mut v: Vec<u16> = Vec::new();
    v.reserve(255);
    let mut p = v.as_mut_ptr();
    let len = v.len();
    let cap = v.capacity();
    let mut read_len = 0;
    unsafe {
        mem::forget(v);
        read_len = unsafe { user32::GetWindowTextW(handle as winapi::HWND, p, 255) };
        if read_len > 0 {
            return String::from_utf16_lossy(Vec::from_raw_parts(p, read_len as usize, cap).as_slice());
        } else {
            return "".to_string();
        }
    }
}
```

I think, that this vector based memory allocation is rather bizarre. So I'm looking for more easier way to cast `LPCWSTR` to `std::String`

Comment: I don't have an answer (I'm not familiar with Rust) but I'm going to guess that `i32` is a 32-bit integer. `HWND`s (and in fact, all handles) are pointers, so this might break on 64-bit Windows; if not now, then at some point in the future. You should be using a pointer-sized integer if you don't want to expose the `HWND` type directly.

Comment: `i32` or maybe `i64` here used for easier transfering global `HWND`'s via `Arc` and easier thread syncronizing. But that not the issue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the `str` has no (im-)mutability guarantees, just like `u8` has no guarantees, it's just a type. [It's entirely possible to have a `&mut str`, there just aren't that many uses for it](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/26241). The `String` type is [definitely mutable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/collections/string/struct.String.html#method.push).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your situation, you always want a maximum of 255 bytes, so you can use an array instead of a vector. This reduces the entire boilerplate to a `mem::uninitialized()` call, an `as_mut_ptr()` call and a slicing operation.

```
unsafe {
    let mut v: [u16; 255] = mem::uninitialized();
    let read_len = user32::GetWindowTextW(
        handle as winapi::HWND,
        v.as_mut_ptr(),
        255,
    );
    String::from_utf16_lossy(&v[0..read_len])
}
```

In case you wanted to use a `Vec`, there's an easier way than to destroy the vec and re-create it. You can write to the `Vec`'s content directly and let Rust handle everything else.

```
let mut v: Vec<u16> = Vec::with_capacity(255);
unsafe {
    let read_len = user32::GetWindowTextW(
        handle as winapi::HWND,
        v.as_mut_ptr(),
        v.capacity(),
    );
    v.set_len(read_len); // this is undefined behavior if read_len > v.capacity()
    String::from_utf16_lossy(&v)
}
```

As a side-note, it is idiomatic in Rust to not use `return` on the last statement in a function, but to simply let the expression stand there without a semicolon. In your original code, the final if-expression could be written as

```
if read_len > 0 {
    String::from_utf16_lossy(Vec::from_raw_parts(p, read_len as usize, cap).as_slice())
} else {
    "".to_string()
}
```

but I removed the entire condition from my samples, as it is unnecessary to handle `0` read characters differently from `n` characters.

Comment: Great answer. Big thanks to you. I've just misunderstood some parts of documentation. Btw, my code is producing memory leak in 32-bit version of compiler. As i think its there `mem::forget(v);`

Comment: Your code only creates a memory leak if `read_len` is `0`, because then you never take back control of the `Vec`.